# Some kind of encryption in C++

Tags: c++, homework, cryptography

It's my university task. Can I get some opinions on it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

string toBinary(short n) {
   string r;
   while(n != 0) {
      r = ( n % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1" ) + r;
      n /= 2;
   }
   return r;
}

int has_even_parity(int c) {
   int k = 0;
   if (c != 0)
      k++;
if ((c & 0x2) >> 1 == 1)
    k++;
if ((c & 0x4) >> 2 == 1)
    k++;
if ((c & 0x8) >> 3 == 1)
    k++;
if ((c & 0x10) >> 4 == 1)
    k++;
if ((c & 0x20) >> 5 == 1)
    k++;
if ((c & 0x40) >> 6 == 1)
    k++;
if ((c & 0x80) >> 7 == 1)
    k++;
 return k % 2;
}

char decode(short int a) {
  char result;
  unsigned short int mask = 0b0111111110000000;
  return (char)((a & mask) >> 7);
}

int main() {
short int result[64];
string str;
vector<string> text_list;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    getline(cin, str);
    text_list.push_back(str);
}
cout << endl;
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < text_list.size(); i++) {
    string l = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < text_list[i].size(); j++) {
        short int c_ = text_list[i][j];
        short int l_ = 0b0000000;
        c_ = l_ | c_;
        result[k] = (short) has_even_parity(c_);
        result[k] = result[k] << 8;
        result[k] = result[k] | c_;
        result[k] = result[k] << 1;
        c_ = (short) (has_even_parity(i) ^ has_even_parity(j));

        result[k] = result[k] | c_;
        result[k] = result[k] << 3;
        result[k] = (short) (result[k] | i);

        result[k] = result[k] << 3;
        result[k] = (short) (result[k] | j);

        l += decode(result[k]);
        k++;
    }
    cout << l << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

I have input as text 8 letters x 8 lines, 2 bytes for one letter.

1. In bit 0-2 number of line
2. In bit 3-5 number of position in line
3. In bit 6 parity bit of 1) and 2)
4. In bit 7-14 ASCII code of letter
5. In bit 15 parity bit of 4)

And after, decode letter.

Comment: `has_even_parity` is returns `true` for `c==2`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using namespace std;` is a bad habit. It's not that tedious to write std:: a few times and you get less name collisions on things you define.

---

Your indentation is inconsistent. This makes it difficult to follow the control flow.

---

The even parity can be discovered with repeated xors:

```
int has_even_parity(int c) {
   c ^= c >> 4;
   c ^= c >> 2;
   c ^= c >> 1;
   return ! (c&1);
}
```

---

```
short int l_ = 0b0000000;
c_ = l_ | c_;
```

This doesn't do anything.

---

I suggest adding some underscores in the binary literals to group the digits:

```
unsigned short int mask = 0b0111_1111_1000_0000;
```

This makes it easier to tell at a glance that there are 7 zeros at the end and that you meant for them to be there. Though once you are more comfortable with hexadecimal then `0x7f80` is just as clear.

Comment: Actually I'd suggest using Hex or Octal rather than binary constants.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I prefer binary over octal (at least until they adopt a `0o` syntax for octal literals)

Comment: Yeah, I prefer Hex myself, shorter and clearer, and it does have the 0x infront. Too easy to make a typo with binary.

Comment: @pacmaninbw though there's less space for unnoticed typos with digit grouping using `_`.